# Javascript object loop is only appending the last iterated element to another object

Tags: javascript

I have a series of loops, within the final loop a javascript object is created. The object changes on each iteration, for example:

```
// iteration 1: {Belmonte: 0.14625} (index):65
// iteration 2: {Castelo Branco: 0.286} (index):65
// iteration 3: {Belmonte: 0.14625} (index):65
// iteration 4: {Castelo Branco: 0.286}
// ... etc
```

I want to append each (4) versions of the object to another object, but I am only able to append the final version #4: `{Castelo Branco: 0.286}`. I understand why this is happening, but can't find a solution. I have created an example (check the console output): http://jsfiddle.net/LUAj3/

**UPDATE**

I **solved** the issue by placing `i` into a function, thus creating its own scope.

Comment: I'm sure you realize that `pck[i]` never changes in that innermost loop, but only in the outermost loop, so you're trying to add the object to the same place. Clearly you can't have 4 objects in one location, so perhaps you need an Array there instead. Whatever the solution, it's going to involve rethinking the data structure of your result.

Comment: When I click on your link, I don't get any results after clicking run.  I don't see an option for console output.

Comment: @cookie monster, yes, the issue is clear, but I was just wondering if there was an elegant solution that would create the desired final object.

Comment: There's no solution to storing multiple objects in one location other than to put them in an Array or in another plain Object.

Comment: @cookie monster, I was thinking about 'freezing' the state of `prObj`  with: `JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( prObj ) );`, but I would need to create a variable name dynamically

Comment: @tom, I meant to inspect the browser, with firebug for example

Answer (score 0):

I did a very quick look over your jsfiddle, so take what I'm saying with a grain of salt.

In your example, this line `catIndicator[pck[i]]` remains the same when you loop through your inner loops, since in each iteration of your inner loops the value of `i` doesn't change, so you're overriding that value.

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you'd need to use multidimensional arrays like `catIndicator[pck[i][j][key]]`. That may not be the correct order, depending on how you want to set up your data object, but I believe it gets the point across.

Word to the wise, try to keep your examples as small and to the point as possible. Most people on SO will move on to another question if they see the example is too complicated for a quick answer. If you adjust your example so that only the problem code is highlighted, I'm sure you'll get more responses.